# Can we say "Readers will have little trouble to keep track of them"?

Tags: grammaticality, complements

Is *keeping track* a gerund in the sentence?

1. Readers will have little trouble **keeping track** of them.

If *keeping track* is a gerund, does that mean that we could also use an infinitive instead with no change in meaning or acceptability?

2. Readers will have little trouble **to keep track** of them?

Comment: I would say that it is a verb, for two reasons. Firstly it has a subject since the readers are doing the keeping track and secondly you can't, in this context, apply an article to it. If you change the sentence structure to "Readers will have little trouble with _the_ keeping track of them"  the 'keeping' becomes a gerund. However that structure is not commonly used. The use of the infinitive 'to keep' is not appropriate in this case.

Comment: It doesn't matter. All you need to know is that it is a verb. Nowadays. we lump both _ing_ verb forms together, simply calling them 'gerund-participles'

Comment: If it were a gerund, it would be the subject or the object, and this is neither.

Comment: @BoldBen The readers are keeping track? The readers are having little trouble.

Comment: @Lambie Good point, but if they  are having little trouble then they are keeping track.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of the form of "keeping track", the structure is [ "have trouble" + verb-"ing" ], so no, it cannot be replaced by an infinitive.

Further, it's not the case that infinitives can generally replace gerunds. And in places where the grammar is still good, the meaning is often different.

Answer (score 1):

You should always try and make a sentence with the gerund phrase to see if it works:

**Keeping track of answers is not easy**.

Does that work? Answer: Yes, it does. **It means the activity of keeping track of something will be easy.**

**Compare that to**:

You must make a big effort **to** keep track of answers.
You must make a big effort for the purpose of keeping track of answers.

The **to-infinitive shows **purpose** or necessity or some goal or other or why something is done.**

If you use: Readers will have little trouble to keep track of them (for the purpose of keeping track of them) with the new system. (For example).

The purpose pointed to is the new system.

The two are grammatical but they would not mean the same thing exactly.

Here's a useful overview of to-infinitives:

[Collins_to infinitive](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/us/easy-learning/how-do-you-use-the-to-infinitive-in-english)